# Razor Class Library doesn't include Views in DLL

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, csproj, razor-class-library

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC application (written in F#) using `.Net Core 3` that has the views in an external Razor Class Library (because you can't mix C# and F#), however, when I run the application the views are not found.

The MVC application does have a reference to the class-library however when I looked at the class-library DLL using dotPeek it did not have any compiled views in it:

[image: dotPeek dissasembly]

This is the `csproj` of the Razor class library:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SportsStore.Infrastructure\SportsStore.Infrastructure.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SportsStore.Models\SportsStore.Models.fsproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SportsStore.TagHelpers\SportsStore.TagHelpers.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And there **are** Views in the project:

[image: Razor class libary Solution Explorer]

I am guessing that the `csproj` file is most likely wrong, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View are embedded resources in the RCL. You access them just as if they were physically in the project at the same filesystem locations. The issue here, I think, is that you have the views at the project root instead of under `Views`/`Pages`, which is where views will be searched for by convention.

You can alter that convention, but you'd need to then do that on every project that uses this RCL, and it's going to be complicated, because you'll need to add each folder individually as a separate location for searching for views, since there's no common root folder. The better solution is to follow the convention and actually put your views under a `Views` directory. In other words, instead of `{project root}/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, it should be `{project root}/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: Firstly, I only intend to use the RCL for this project.
Secondly, the project already has the `.Views` at the end for this purpose and I can't take that away because no two projects can have the same name.

Comment: Then there's no point to having the RCL. If the code isn't reusable and isn't intended to be reusable, then just keep in the main project. All you're doing is adding extra complexity for no purpose.

Comment: The `.Views` part of the name constitutes the namespace. It has absolutely zero to do with how the views are referenced. You can keep `.Views` at the end if you like, but you *still* need a `Views` directory. It's not a replacement.

Comment: The reason I have an RCL is because of:

_"I have an ASP.Net Core MVC application (written in F#) using .Net Core 3 that has the views in an external Razor Class Library (because you can't mix C# and F#)"_

Comment: Okay. Doesn't change anything though. You still need a `Views` directory in the RCL. Think of it as an ASP.NET Core project that you just don't run directly. You wouldn't be able to access any views directly in the project if they weren't under some common directory, which is either `Views` or `Pages` by convention. You cannot do so here, either. The fact that `.Views` is part of the namespace is meaningless here, because views are not referenced by namespace, but by filesystem path.

Comment: aren't they referenced by class name?
I thought the path was compiled into the name of the class and is then referenced by that from the View Engine.

Comment: A class is generated by Razor to back the view, but that is not how the view is referenced. It's referenced via its filesystem location.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do it you can like this:

In API project (csproj, fproj) force razor files to be excluded from compile at build, and make sure compiling at runtime will work (all razor and C# dependencies)

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
<MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
```

Now we have to make sure that at build or publish views are copied. So for any view in project (csproj) where is declared manually you have to add this

```
 <None Include="Account\Login.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
```

But then again, this approach is when you want to compile yourself the views, for example for a email generation or for a document generation, so I don't think this is what you are looking. Truly if you need it for a controller action result, view is compiled in project assembly.

Comment: This will not work for an RCL. The RCL is referenced as a class library, so the views *must* be embedded in the DLL in order to come along for the ride.

Comment: I agree with second part, for the first part, my bad, in netcoreapp3.0 might not work din't tested, for 2.2 guarantee it does https://preview.tinyurl.com/y52zull4